# Outputting multiple queries to separate files

Tags: mysql, bash, hadoop, hive, output

I'm using Hive, but that's essentially SQL.

In my code, I wrote two queries that draws from the same temporary table.

The temporary table they're utilizing takes some time to make, so I'd like to execute both queries in the same `hive -e "command" command` so I won't have to build the temporary table twice.

Is there a way to select two different output files for the two different commands?

It seems like this example

```
echo 'hello' | tee aa bb
```

just outputs *hello* to both *aa* and *bb*, which isn't quite what I want.

Comment: Do you mean `echo 'hello' | tee - > aa`?

Comment: Possibly? What would that do?

Comment: Assuming that loading the table is pretty time intensive, versus scripting an edit to split one file apart how about `hive -e "cmd1" -e "echo -----sep line----"  -e "cmd2" > mergedOutFile.txt ; awk 'BEGIN{outfile="cmd1.out"} NR==FNR && $0 !~ /sep line/ {print $0 > outFile } $0~/sep line/{outfile=cmd2.out; next}NR!=FNR{print $0 > outfile} mergedOutFile.txt` You'll have to get `hive` to run more than 1 command in an invocation. I'm just guessing at what those arguments would look like. Sorry don't have time to test this. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know hive, but is there a way to "chain" commands, similar to bash/sed/lots of other things. eg:

```
cat foo; cat bar
```

Probably too simplistic, but the first thing that popped into my head.

Comment: I can write out both queries in the same command. I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to get outputs in different files for different select statements. Right now, two different tables are being outputted into one file, but I'd like them to be separate.

Comment: ahhhhh, use some redirection then :) I cobbled this together from a few other questions:

Comment: >&2 echo foo; echo bar |tee out 2>&1 >errout

Comment: Hm. Comment fail, but yeah, that's it. Just tested it. basically, the first "echo" goes to stderr, and the second one goes to stdout. tee captures the stdout stuff and outputs to the file named "out" and all the stderr stuff goes to a file named "errout"

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working, I don't think I can partition the two different selects like that and still be able to hold the temporary table. Thanks though!